# Using a function in an insert statement in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Is it possible to use a user defined function in an insert statement in slick? This is what my tables look like, but I'm getting an error when I try to run it.

```
case class User(username: String, email: String)

class Users(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

    def username = column[String]("username", O.PrimaryKey)
    def email = column[String]("email", O.NotNull)
    def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
    def preferences = column[JsValue]("preferences")

    def idx = index("idx_users_email", email, unique = true)

    def group = foreignKey("fk_group", username, groups)(_.groupname)

    def * = (username, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    def withPassword = (username, email, password) <>[(User, String), (String, String, String)](
                                        { case (u: String, e: String, p: String) => (User(u, e), p)},
                                        { case (r: User, p: String) => Some((r.username, r.email, p))}
                                        )
}

object users extends TableQuery(new Users(_)) {

  val crypt = SimpleFunction.binary[String, String, String]("crypt")
  val gen_salt = SimpleFunction.binary[String, Option[Int], String]("gen_salt")

  def createUser(u: String, e: String, p: String)(implicit session: Session) = {
      val user = User(u, e)

      val s = this.map {c =>(c.username, c.password, users.crypt(c.password, users.gen_salt(LiteralColumn("bf"), LiteralColumn(7))))}
      s insertExpr (u, e, p)
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the error

> SlickException: : Cannot use node
>   scala.slick.lifted.SimpleFunction$$anon$2@69ade8b0 crypt, false for
>   inserting data

I've tried several different ways of trying to get my inserts to work. Including this:

```
def withPassword = (username, email, users.crypt(password, users.gen_salt(LiteralColumn("bf"), LiteralColumn(7)))) <>[(User, String), (String, String, String)](
                                        { case (u: String, e: String, p: String) => (User(u, e), p)},
                                        { case (r: User, p: String) => Some((r.username, r.email, p))}
                                        )
```

Am I just expecting too much for slick to be able to do what I want to and just break down and use raw SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported, but we have a ticket for it with unclear future: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/928

Besides, encryption is almost always better handled on the client-level. Database-level encryption has very limited security guarantees, because you are sending the keys to the place where the encrypted data is stored. More info in the above ticket.

Comment: Good to know. I'm not trying to increase security or anything. I'm just trying to learn some more advanced features of slick, and this seemed like a cool feature of postgres that might